# How to concatenate the query arguments to the query in a scope in Laravel using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a complicate query where there is an unknown number of postalcode areas posted to my api. At the moment I almost found the solution, but I can't concatenate my whereBetween parameters to the Query in the scope. I get the error query can't be casted to string, which also makes sense.

The array passed to the scope has the following structure:         `$plz = [[10000, 11000], [34200, 34500]];`

Here is my code in the scope:

```
public function scopePlz($query, $plz)
{
    $queryString = '';
    foreach ($plz as $index => $single) {
        $queryString .=
            $index == 0
                ? "->whereBetween('postalcode_int', [$single[0], $single[1]])"
                : "->orWhereBetween('postalcode_int', [$single[0], $single[1]])";
    }
    return $query . $queryString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
public function scopePlz($query, $plz)
{
    $first = array_shift($plz);

    $query->whereBetween('postalcode_int', [$first[0], $first[1]]);

    foreach ($plz as $single) {
        $query->orWhereBetween('postalcode_int', [$single[0], $single[1]]);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Get the first item from the array, add it like a where and then run the rest of the array through a foreach.

If you want one big where statement for all these postal codes, wrap this scope in an separate where method.

Comment: Bedankt ;)! I guess I misunderstood how the query object worked, that solved it! Thanks again!